# Why is a large sound file causing my p5.js sketch to freeze?

Tags: p5.js

I have a p5.js Sketch - running locally (macbook - 3.1 GHz Intel Core i5) and also here:
https://editor.p5js.org/svsdesign/sketches/Klfa4s4zU

Running the sketch with the "skit-sample.mp3" sound file works as expected.

This is a relatively small / short file, and I want to be able to run the sketch with larger / longer sound files - i.e. "chris_inperspective-dragons_in_the_world_compressed.mp3"(see the sketch markup for file, its commented out atm).

If I try and run the sketch with this longer file, it will ultimately freeze my browser.

I'm relatively new to p5.js - so my code might have some inherent flaws - maybe some looping issues? Any advice or pointers would be great!

Comment: Can you please isolate your problem in a [mcve]? For example can you just load and play the sound without all that extra code?

Comment: @KevinWorkman - Yes, the above Sketch works as expected. The issue starts if I replace the current mp3 file with a longer file.

Comment: I get crashes on both samples.  could be memory issues

Comment: In the assets there are two files named the same. gif.worker.js